# Scene with passport connected to wires

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bourne-legacy

in "The Bourne Legacy" what was Aaron Cross doing in the scene where he had the camera and wires connected to the passport?

Comment: *emphasized text*Thank you. I've been stumped on that one But it shows her getting passport pic taken after she's on the run when the CIA team is watching for her

Answer (score 17):

He is using [High Voltage to de-magnetize](http://dr.archives.pdx.edu/xmlui/handle/psu/7363) a hidden identifying strip in the passport.  Since the lack of the presence of this strip doesn't cause any issues at the Airport, we are to assume that her passport had this magnetic identifier because of her job, to keep tabs on her travel.  By disabling it, she is able to use the passport and garner no additional attention.

**addition**
He still needed to use her passport as a base to work from, in providing her with credentials to travel with.  Using a new picture on the old passport and/or altering the document would be easier than obtaining a new passport.

Comment: 2.5 years later, thank you. Totally didn't see that last time I watched it.

Comment: Looks like [RFID-Zapper](https://www.rfidjournal.com/articles/view?2098) - source of electromagnetic pulse for killing an [RFID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) tag.

Answer (score -1):

If you freeze the image as he is putting the putty and wires on the passport, you can see her picture on it with the name June Munroe clearly visible typed onto the passport.  It looks to me like he is adding her photo to one of his dummy passports with the fake name June Munroe already on it.  I have no idea what he is doing with the voltage and the wire, other than possibly destroying its ability to be read by a scanner.  Since the name June Munroe is typed into this passport, then he could not be using her real passport as the base to work with as suggested.